# How to decode this code?

Tags: decode, huffman-code, compression

I have encountered what seems like a Huffman tree and a string of data that I need to decode.

So my question is: How to decode this string using the Huffman Tree?

Comment: How did you convert to binary ? Also, is the tree continuing after the B and O ? Like, _ABCDE... and MNOPQL...

Comment: Then it is a broken tree. A huffman tree is not supposed to have "null" leafs, that's a waste of bits because it means some code could be shorter, and huffman trees are optimal so it's not a huffman tree. But it's still a prefix code so you can still use it, if you must.

Comment: The binary string you have can't be parsed with this tree. Either the tree is incomplete, or the conversion is not good. I still have no idea how this conversion was done.

Comment: Ok well let's assume that both the tree and that binary string are valid. The first two bits 10 decode to M, and then we get stuck because none of the codes are a prefix of 11111. So, something must have gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: This converter clearly indicate "max 4294967295". Don't you have any hint on how to decode this decimal ? It doesn't look like a normal number, there is a lot of 0s.

Comment: If the decoded string has 'the' and 'is', then the tree continue below what is shown. That makes sense since _AB and MNO look like it could be continued with CDEF... and PQRS...

Comment: That's only speculation, but it makes sense to continue the pattern. C would be 01110, D 011110, P 11110, Q 111110 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tree in the image is supposed to be continued. After B comes C,D... and after O comes P,Q... This means C is coded 01110, D is coded 011110, P is 11110 ...

Knowing that the string contains 'the' and 'is', there is a high chance that the whole string is started by 'the'.

With this tree, 'the' is coded 111111110 0111111110 0111110.

Seeing that, it is easy to deduce the decimal encoding, since it happens to perfectly match this. "111111110 0111111110 0111110" is 8x1 + 0 + 0 + 8x1 + 0 + 0 + 5x1 + 0. In short, 80080050. A number indicates a sequence of 1, and 0 means a 0. This also means that 10 is ambiguous, but well, there is only 2 possibilities.

Now you can decode the rest.